# Recognize custom login page as wp-login.php

Tags: login

I created a custom login page and would like it to take the place of the wp-login.php page completely.

For example, so that the `login_head` function addresses only the new customized login page.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks a lot to those who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customize the login page by using the plugin. Some of the famous plugins are mentioned here:

- [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/)
- [LoginPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loginpress/)
- [Tailored Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-customizer/)
- [Login Designer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-designer/)

Comment: Hi Zain, I try to explain myself better. I have already created the customized login page by code.

Now I would like it to take the place of wp-login.php completely since I get an error in creating the password.